# Run multiple instances of MySQL on a single Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Is it possible to install multiple MySQL Servers instances on an Ubuntu Server, like I can do on Windows Server?

The goal is to have 10 MySQL Server instances in one Ubuntu Server installed, each MySQL Server with its own port number and IP address.

Comment: Use a systemd instantiated service as described on: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html#systemd-multiple-mysql-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is definitely possible. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-unix-servers.html is a good reference.

**Alternative #1:**
My suggestion based on MySQL's reference is that you make 10 copies of your my.cnf and add them to your `/etc/rc.local`. In that case you should preferably make use of a tool such as monit to monitor the status and uptime of the instances. Second alternative is to modify the existing start-up script.

The following script is not tested, but gives you an idea of what needs to be done. It loops over 10 MySQL servers, and copy a separate config, create a separate user and data directory, and increment the port number from 3306 to 3317. Make sure to go over the rc.local to change the IP address to your desired IPs, before running rc.local or restarting your server.

Also make sure to configure sane settings in terms of performance utilization to handle all these servers at once. There may be conflicts with ACLs such as SELinux or AppArmor. If you run into problems with this solution and can't figure it out, please leave a comment.

```bash
mv /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.local.bak
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' > /etc/rc.local
chmod 0755 /etc/rc.local
cd /etc/mysql
port=3306
for i in {1..10}
do
   cp my.cnf my-${port}.cnf
   sed -i 's/socket.*/socket\=\/var\/run\/mysqld\/mysqld-${port}.sock/' my-${port}.cnf
   echo "mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql/my-${port}.cnf --bind-address=127.0.0.${i} --port=$port --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-${port} " >> /etc/rc.local
   useradd -d /nonexistent -s /bin/false -c "MySQL server listening on ${port}"
   mkdir -m 0700 /var/lib/mysql-${port}
   mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/var/lib/mysql-${port} --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-${port}/data
   port=$(expr $port + 1)
done
echo 'exit 0' >> /etc/rc.local
mv my.cnf my.cnf.bak
update-rc.d -f mysql remove
```

**Alternative #2:**
Use mysqld_multi as described on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-multi.html.

**Alternative #3:**
A very easy and clean solution would be to install docker and run 10 separate containers with MySQL, with different port and ip numbers. You can setup those overrides in your `Dockerfile`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much William Sandin and Max Coates. As we seen, the Market tendency is to use Containers, so i´ll follow your suggestions about docker.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either containerization or a type 2 hypervisor's to achieve what you need (multiple instances of mysql on the same host). I would suggest in your case [using Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for containerization.

If your not familiar with containers think of them as lightweight VM's with the Hypervisor instead being the container engine (docker).

Unlike VM's though, containers don't require a full blown OS or required lib/bins. The same Linux kernel and libraries can be shared between multiple containers running on the host which makes them more efficient and in some cases easier to manage with the separation between containers.

**Heres the architecture overview in comparison to Hypervisors:**
[image: architectural differences between VMs and Containers]

Comment: Thank you so much for your approach Max Coates, i will try and i give you a Feedback. (Y)